# Flavors, Google api, release

Tags: android, google-api, release, drive, android-productflavors

I've published three apps build on the same code out of three different flavors. I use Google drive api. Only first install/run of my apps from Google Play works as expected. After that apps won't connect to google account.

I tried assigning different fingerprints to each app build (aplicationId + (signed) SHA1) and also created an unrestricted api key and tried using it.
All with the same success.

What am I doing wrong?

```
productFlavors {
    Jiva {
        applicationId "com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "7.0 Google Drive Production"
        flavorDimensions "jiva"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "apk_key", "AIzaSyDvDzLhy377uSZ0qDastw5WT2ajhXCDkcU"
        resValue "string", "studio_setup", "Studio setup"
    }
    Open {
        minSdkVersion 21
        applicationId 'com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlogOpen'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        versionCode 10
        versionName '10.0 Google drive Prod'
        flavorDimensions "gym"
        resValue "string", "apk_key", "AIzaSyDvDzLhy377uSZ0qDastw5WT2ajhXCDkcU"
        resValue "string", "studio_setup", "Gym setup"
    }
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can check :)

Comment: I've added flavour section from gradle, yet I am not sure it will help much. The question as I see it is about google api functionality and limitations.